# Japanese displays weirdly in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, fonts

When I use chrome, hiragana and katakana renders in this washed-out and thin font. I've checked the font settings and even downloaded the advanced font settings--where the non-kanji renders fine for some reason--but nothing seems to work. I've tried every Japanese font in the settings but they all give the exact same result.

Here's a comparison image with firefox:

[image]

Due to all the testing I'm guessing it's not a problem with the font. But what is the issue then?

Comment: I found someone saying they had a similar problem and [this extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/%E9%83%A8%E5%88%86%E5%BC%B7%E5%88%B6%E3%83%A1%E3%82%A4%E3%83%AA%E3%82%AA%E3%81%A1%E3%82%83%E3%82%93/kmjcmncjhdnaealenhoohllicfkdojpb?utm_source=chrome-app-launcher-info-dialog) resolved it for them, might be worth a try? I can't read Japanese so I'm fairly clueless, so I won't propose this as an answer, just a suggestion.

Comment: Worked perfectly, would you mind putting this as an answer?

Comment: Done, glad it worked for you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tested this as I can't speak Japanese, but after some research, other sources claim that [this extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/%E9%83%A8%E5%88%86%E5%BC%B7%E5%88%B6%E3%83%A1%E3%82%A4%E3%83%AA%E3%82%AA%E3%81%A1%E3%82%83%E3%82%93/kmjcmncjhdnaealenhoohllicfkdojpb?utm_source=chrome-app-launcher-info-dialog) for Google Chrome should resolve your problem.

[image]